# Why does Babel copy an array before passing it to concat for array spread operator?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, babeljs

My code:

```
const allMessages = [ ...resultMessages, ...oldNotErrorMessages ];
```

Babel [convert to](https://babeljs.io/repl/#?babili=false&browsers=&build=&builtIns=false&code_lz=MYewdgzgLgBAhgGwQWQKYQnA5umBeGAbRgDoyAndAVwSjQ23QBpSyQEATAORCgFFy5EOXqYcEGAF0A3EA&debug=false&forceAllTransforms=false&shippedProposals=false&circleciRepo=&evaluate=true&fileSize=false&lineWrap=true&presets=es2015%2Creact%2Cstage-2%2Cenv&prettier=true&targets=&version=6.26.0&envVersion=1.6.2)

```
function _toConsumableArray(arr) {
  if (Array.isArray(arr)) {
    for (var i = 0, arr2 = Array(arr.length); i < arr.length; i++) {
      arr2[i] = arr[i];
    }
    return arr2;
  } else {
    return Array.from(arr);
  }
}

var allMessages = [].concat(
  _toConsumableArray(resultMessages),
  _toConsumableArray(oldNotErrorMessages)
);
```

Why does Babel copy an array if it array before passing it to concat? Why not `if(Array.isArray(arr)) return arr;`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nicolò Ribaudo answer on [github](https://github.com/babel/babel/issues/7332#issuecomment-363232403)

> Holes needs to be conveted to undeifned

```
> [ 0, ...[ 1, , 2 ] ]
[0, 1, undefined, 2]

> [ 0 ].concat([ 1, , 2 ])
[0, 1, empty, 2]

> [ 0 ].concat(_toConsumableArray([ 1, , 2 ]))
[0, 1, undefined, 2]
```

Answer (score 1):

[Array.prototype.concat](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/concat) will put all the arguments into the new array no matter what it is which isn't how the [spread operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Spread_operator) should work.

Take these two examples.

```js
console.log([].concat(1, true));

console.log([].concat(Array.from(1), Array.from(true)));
```

The first one will return an array with 1 and true while [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) will filter out those (since they are not iterable or array-like) so the result will be an empty array.

If we try to run the spread operator in a browser that supports it natively we'll see that this is how it should work.

```js
[...true];
```

So while this might seem like a non-optimal way of doing it they are just making sure that the operator works according to specs.

Comment: I'm interesting about if (Array.isArray(arr)) { //copy array }. Why copy, not return arr?

Comment: Then I have no idea I'm afraid. The method doesn't have any comments about it in the source files but my best guess would be that the same helper is used in some other plugin and they needed a new array since they are modifying it somehow. You could raise an issue about this on github and see if the developers know the reason.